# Error in access function variable as static variable

Tags: php, oop, static

In my demo project I want to access static variable of some class, but those variable name are passing dynamically. am trying to use function variable like given below:

```
public function filterBy($params)
    {
        foreach ($params as $key=>$value) {
            $filter_field_name = strtoupper($key);
            $this->criteria->add(ProductPeer::$filter_field_name, $value, Criteria::EQUAL);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

It gives me error

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property:
>   ProductPeer::$filter_field_name in
>   /home/sfprojects/shopme/lib/product/ProductDb.php on line 47

Though if I use `ProductPeer::STATUS` instead of `ProductPeer::$filter_field_name` then it works.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `constant()` that can do this:

```
constant('ProductPeer::' . $filter_field_name);
```

Comment: Yup, works perfect! thanks. though I don't know reason behind it, if you can tell reason behind access via constant function then it would be helpful

Comment: I suppose that the `$` accesses only properties of the class, whereas constants are a separate language construct which works different.

Answer (score 0):

$this->criteria->add(ProductPeer::$$filter_field_name, $value, Criteria::EQUAL);

Use double dollar sign for reference of other variable. Like $$filter_field_name